# How to consume and produce new UTXO to same script with different Datum?

Tags: plutus, eutxo

I am trying to consume old UTXO at stript and produce new one with new Datum.
Validator is validating ok but not sure why new utxo with updated datum is not available.

current utxos holds one utxo with Datum DAccept

this is how i am constructing tx

```
let tx = collectFromScript  utxos redeemer  <>  Constraints.mustPayToTheScript DRecv tAmt
```

TxConstraint looks something like this

```
TxConstraints {
  txConstraints = [MustIncludeDatum (Datum {getDatum = Constr 2 []})], # constr 2 = DRecv 
  txOwnInputs = [
     InputConstraint {icRedeemer = ReceiveItem \"key_C1\", icTxOutRef = TxOutRef {
       txOutRefId = a3d3cac6f6c2c2c9152baaa97e1f807dbdeee3ff7f1b47d0cfc1d3b6329091e5, txOutRefIdx = 1}
     }], 
   txOwnOutputs = [
      OutputConstraint {ocDatum = DRecv, ocValue = Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",20000000)])])}
   ]
}
```

Redeemer looks something like this

```
 ReceiveItem k ->                                                                                                                                                                        
   traceIfFalse  "Must output DRecv datum" (isScriptOpHasDatum DRecv)  &&                                                                                                                
   traceIfFalse  "Must have Datum" (dtm == DAccept)  &&
```

```
 scriptOutput :: TxOut                                                                                                                                                                   
 scriptOutput = case getContinuingOutputs ctx of                                                                                                                                         
   [o] -> o                                                                                                                                                                              
     _ -> traceError "More than one outputs"                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                            
 scriptOutputDtm :: Maybe  DeliveryStatus                                                                                                                                                
     scriptOutputDtm = do                                                                                                                                                                    
       dtmHash <-  txOutDatum  scriptOutput                                                                                                                                                  
      Datum d <-  findDatum dtmHash info                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                           
     PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData  d                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                            
 isScriptOpHasDatum :: DeliveryStatus -> Bool                                                                                                                                            
 isScriptOpHasDatum d = scriptOutputDtm  == Just d
```

above redeemer is working fine but tx is not producing new output with `DRecv` Datum

Comment: could you please share what the ```isScriptOpHasDatum``` function is doing?

Comment: @Michele sure its just checks if datum is there in output. added code

Comment: Issue was in another validation i was not calculating inputs correctly, its solved now thanks.

Comment: Hi Piyush, it will help us a lot if you can share with the community the solution to your problem in a post. Thank you.

Comment: my issue was i didn't log much Trace in TraceConfig so it was not giving another TraceError above code is fine